# KNN works in `class` but not `caret` (Too many ties)

Tags: r, machine-learning, knn

I am making a KNN algorithm to predict `close_price` with about 80,000 rows of this data.

```
# A tibble: 81,334 x 12
   latitude longitude close_date          close_price    id address      country state zip   date        week  year
      <dbl>     <dbl> <dttm>                    <dbl> <int> <fct>        <fct>   <fct> <fct> <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1     36.4     -98.7 2014-08-05 06:34:00     147504.     2 US-412, Fai… USA     OK    73737 2014-08-05    31  2014
 2     36.6     -97.9 2014-08-12 23:48:00     137401.     3 N2850 Rd, E… USA     OK    73703 2014-08-12    32  2014
 3     36.6     -97.9 2014-08-09 04:00:40     239105.     5 Craig Rd, P… USA     OK    73766 2014-08-09    32  2014
 4     36.5     -98.3 2014-08-07 15:18:18     270885.     6 62161 Caddo… USA     OK    73741 2014-08-07    32  2014
```

I am trying to start out with a simple model that predicts the close price as a function of the week.

```
library(caret)
data_small <- data %>% select(close_price, week)
training.samples <- data_small$close_price %>%
  createDataPartition(p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
train.data  <- data_small[training.samples, ]
test.data <- data_small[-training.samples, ]
```

I find that I can make predictions using `knn()` from `class`.

```
library(class)
modelKNN <- knn(train.data, test.data, cl = train.data$close_price, k = 4, l = 0, prob = FALSE, use.all = TRUE)
```

But when I try to do it with caret, I get an error.

```
model <- train(close_price~ ., data = train.data, method = "knn")
```

It serves me back:

> Warning messages:
>
> 1: predictions failed for Resample01: k=5 Error in
>   knnregTrain(train = structure(c(32, 32, 32, 25, 25, 25, 25, 32,  :
>   too many ties in knn
>
> 2: predictions failed for Resample01: k=7 Error in knnregTrain(train =
>   structure(c(32, 32, 32, 25, 25, 25, 25, 32,  :    too many ties in knn
>
> 3: predictions failed for Resample01: k=9 Error in knnregTrain(train =
>   structure(c(32, 32, 32, 25, 25, 25, 25, 32,  :    too many ties in knn

I tried different variants of `train()`, like including `trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10), preProcess = c("center", "scale"), tuneLength = 10` with the same result.

I also want to note that the [prices vary quite a bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqzJD.png) based on the close week.

I looked at a similar question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156229/error-too-many-ties-in-knn-in-r) but their take just uses `class`.

This is the structure of the train data.

```
# A tibble: 65,070 x 2
   close_price  week
         <dbl> <dbl>
 1     147504.    31
 2     239105.    32
 3     270885.    32
 4     228514.    25
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying `k=4` in `caret`, as you did in `class`?